# how to create chat session in quickblox using Email and password

Tags: android, quickblox, groupchat

i am using quickblox chat api for group chat.I am creating chat session using username and password .
this is my code to creatr session for chat.

```
final QBUser user = new QBUser();
        user.setLogin(username);
        user.setPassword(password);

        QBAuth.createSession(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle args) {

                System.out.println("user  id " + session.getUserId());

                user.setId(session.getUserId());
                ((ApplicationSingleton) getParent().getApplication()
                        .getApplicationContext()).setCurrentUser(user);

                loginToChat(user);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                editor.putBoolean("ISCHECKED", false);
                editor.putString("Username", "");
                editor.putString("Password", "");
                editor.commit();

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getParent());
                dialog.setMessage("create session errors: " + errors).create()
                        .show();
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

but i want to create session using email and password.
Anybody have any idea to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The same, but set an email instead of login

```
final QBUser user = new QBUser();
user.setEmail(email);
user.setPassword(password);
```

Comment: i have tried  this but it did not working i am getting error like    '{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}}'

Comment: Please post you log from logcat

Comment: *** RESPONSE *** d5f0de73-88d8-4a00-b91c-b181fe0a3fab ***
 STATUS : 422 
 HEADERS
     Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
     Cache-Control=no-cache
     Connection=keep-alive
     Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
     Date=Mon, 09 Feb 2015 11:19:03 GMT
     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
     Server=nginx/1.0.15
     Status=422 Unprocessable Entity
     Transfer-Encoding=chunked
     X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
     X-Request-Id=4c3518b5fb6dd6b7a7346b0f2b57c877
     X-Runtime=0.006692
     X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
 BODY
     '{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}}'

Comment: I mean request, not response

Comment: === REQUEST ==== 3e3299f5-d122-4b59-ac5f-b1cbfd95484f ===
 REQUEST
     POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
 HEADERS
     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
     QB-SDK=Android 2.1
 PARAMETERS
     application_id=19192
     auth_key=aG3T3kPdMjT9smG
     nonce=1894971789
     timestamp=1423485172
     user[login]=mkgarg99@rocketmail.com
     user[password]=qwerty12345
     signature=fdf706a5543ce74a6da78ee416bb689bde1ec9ac

Comment: Why you use user.setLogin but not user.setEmail?

Comment: Igor is correct. In the request body you're clearly setting the "user[login]" property and not the "user[email]" property. It should say "user[email]=mkgarg99@rocketmail.com". For more on this specific REST call, see: http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_Session_Creation

Comment: don't also use email. use one or the other, not both.

Comment: i am having the same problem i think its something wrong with the sdk coz it's a problem of `@` sign i have create a user with `@` and without `@` to login user with @ sign give the `{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}}` and the other one just pass through